# Inverse Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I have spent hours searching answer to this with no success, so hopefully someone can help me with this.

In the NBA you can bet on how many blocked shots will a player achieve in a game.

Let's say based on the bookamaker's odds there is 62% probability, that certain player will have atleast 2 blocks. I'm pretty sure bookmakers set these odds based on poisson distribution.

My question is, if there is any way to get the initial projected number of the blocks, they are using to get these probabilities, so I can then work with it to get the probability of the same player achieving for example 3 blocks in a game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $P(n\geq 2)=1-P(0)-P(1)=1-(1+\lambda)e^{-\lambda}$ for a Poisson distribution. Solve for $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have to find someone who can solve this for me, because I know only how to use the poisson distribution function in google sheets. Too bad they don't have the inverse function.

Comment: You can solve that equation in WolframAlpha. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1+-+%281+%2B+x%29e%5E%28-x%29+%3D+0.62) the result for $\lambda$ corresponding to $P(n\geq 2)=0.62$.

Comment: Thank's a lot. This is exactly what i needed!